# How to completely remove lamp server and phpmyadmin

Tags: uninstall, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am a newly used lamp server and phpmyadmin.I was trying to install lamp server and phpmyadmin,but it is not working.So,

> i want to completely  remove lamp server and  phpmyadmin.

Also ,give

> a proper steps to fresh  installing  of lamp server and phpmyadmin.

Comment: What do you mean with: *but it is not working*. What do you expect (to see)? What did you tried?

Comment: i was trying different  process..that why it is not working properly and did not configure properly...

Answer (score 1):

To remove the LAMP stack :
1.`sudo apt-get purge mysql-server apache2 php5`
`Note: This assumes you have no other programs that require any of these packages. You might wish to simulate this removal first, and only remove the packages that don't cause removal of something desired.`

2.`sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql`

- And for fresh Installation below is the optimal method 
  [Installing LAMP Stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of getting the lamp to get working on any GNU/LINUX is getting the XAMPP for linux ( https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html ). This one comes with phpmyadmin as well.

If you want to make your own LAMP server, then it might prove to a headache.

Comment: i want lamp not xamp

Comment: well LAMP means LINUX, Apache, MySQL and PHP/Perl . XAMPP for LINUX is one package that makes your job easier. It contains all the things for setting up LAMP - No configuration required.