# How do I simulate removal of the LAMP server on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: lamp, software-uninstall

I realise that for removing the LAMP stack there are several threads already, but without wishing to duplicate the question, how can I simulate removal of LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04 as recommended by Akhil Varma [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447086/how-to-completely-remove-lamp-server-and-phpmyadmin/929090#929090)?

I'm unable to leave a comment there. Especially because many people have experienced problems when removing LAMP, I think a step-by-step guide to testing it out first would be helpful.

I'll be most grateful for any help, as I really need to free up memory.

Comment: your url is broken; goes to a non-existing location. editted if that is not the correct one please edit it ;)

Comment: And I doubt there is a way to test a removal.  You can see what it removes before answering "yes" to it. But the end results ... nope.

Comment: url broken ? Sorry, Rinzwind, but the link's working for me, even when I'm logged out of the site. Here is the full address, though: https://askubuntu.com/questions/447086/how-to-completely-remove-lamp-server-and-phpmyadmin/929090#929090

Comment: Please read the 1st comment carefully. See the revision history if needed.

Comment: Aha, yes, I did indeed misread "editted"[sic] as being the imperative "edit it"(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this is using the aptitude package manager. It's an advanced package manager that even includes an in terminal graphic display. Install it with

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Now you can simply use simulate function with

```
aptitude -s purge phpmyadmin php5 mysql-server
```

(This command is only to show you how it works! I don't know which packages you exactly want to purge so add them yourself)

However this only shows what will be purged, not the actual purging(like @Rinzwind stated.

Comment: This is handy for me to know. I have aptitude installed already, but didn't know about the in terminal graphic manager function, nor how to simulate purges.

Comment: @ReneThomas then could you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes. As explanation rather than justification (ignorance is said to be no excuse), I have only a shallow understanding of how stack exchange forums work, and it never occurred to me that answers can be accepted by a specific action rather than just by a positive comment.